# Modifying several hundred geojson files by adding a feature / attribute

Tags: python, geojson

I have just downloaded several hundred identically formatted geojson files. The problem is none of them have any attributes in their file structure just coordinates. I want to add the following lines at the top of every file using either python2 or python3:

```
   content = {'"type": "FeatureCollection",'
      '"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },'
             '"features": ['
             '{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "%s" }, "geometry":' %i
             }
```

Where i is just the filename. I have tried a variety of things but nothing seems to get all the way there. There always seems to be an error with the string, the combination or the output. I would also like to add a `]}` at the end but that is fairly straightforward append. Any help would be awesome.

```
import json
with open('TestLayer.geojson', 'w') as geojson_file:
data = json.load(geojson_file)
# data is now a dict,
content = {'"type": "FeatureCollection",'
           '"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":  "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },'
           '"features": ['
           '{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "%s" }, "geometry":'
           }
data = content+data
json.dump(data, geojson_file)
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Are you trying to use some kind of JSON library? If you show the code, you're more likely to get a useful result. Also, what does QGIS have to do with the question?

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: your code `content = {'string' 'string' 'string'}` is not valid Python. Also you should make yourself familiar with Pythons indentation syntax. And of course you cannot concatenate a dict with a string like this. Make yourself familiar with Pythons data types.

Answer (score 1):

In your "code example" you seem to mix string and dict.

Though I would use bash (preferably `sed`), you can perfectly use pythons `json` module to edit geojson files.

```
import json
with open('file.geojson', 'w') as geojson_file:
    data = json.load(geojson_file)
    # data is now a dict,
    # you can do whatever you want with it
    json.dump(data, geojson_file)
```

Comment: I just get errors when I run this solution..    return loads(fp.read(),
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: I believe you should make yourself familiar with basic principles of python programming.